# add auto_increment to column of NULL values - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
company_id   |  name 
----------------------
NULL         |  google
NULL         |  amazon
```

All the values in company_id are NULL, and I'd like to replace those values with AUTO_INCREMENTED INT starting from 24,000. However, when I try

```
alter table table_name modify column company_id int AUTO_INCREMENT, add primary key;
```

It throws error `Query 1 ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`
As well as when I run

```
alter table `table_name` modify column `company_id` int AUTO_INCREMENT=24000, add primary key;
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 1) You forget to specify an expression which will be a primary key. 2) You must specify AUTO_INCREMENT table attribute (a) in the same statement (b) before adding PK.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to just add an auto increment column starting at a certain value.  If you want to go the update route, then here is one option friendly for MySQL 8+:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t2
    ON t2.name = t1.name
SET
    company_id = rn + 23999
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
alter table test AUTO_INCREMENT=24000, 
                 modify column company_id int AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                 add primary key (company_id);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=387c7aa8867cc51d0c470f50dd376ee5)

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you don't have an existing PRIMARY KEY, otherwise adding a "second one" will fail.

As for your question, the syntax is incorrect, you want to do:

```
alter table table_name modify column company_id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```